# how to fetch a column in browse_record_list in orm browse method in openERP

Tags: python-2.7, orm, openerp-7

I'm beginner in openERP. I'm trying to get a column in a table. While using ORM browse method and iterating that object i got the result in browse_record_list as **browse_record(table.name,21)**.
I want to fetch that particular id 21 alone through that browse method but instead im getting same browse_record as shown above.

How to fetch that particular column alone.

updated:

```
d_c=None
    dc =None
    dc=self.pool.get('some.table').browse(cr,uid,1,context={})
    if dc:
        d_name = dc.name
        d_id =dc.id
        d_some_id=dc.some_id

    logging.info(d_name)
    logging.info(d_id)
    logging.info(d_some_id)
```

In this code when i saw the log it shows id and name as in the table  as expected,but that some_id alone gives **browse_record(some.table,21)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all the fields of that table from the browsable object.

```
id = browse_record.id
name = browse_record.name
```

Similarly you can access all the relational tables data as well, like customer in sale order.

```
partner_id = sale_order_object.partner_id.id
partner_name = sale_order_object.partner_id.name
```

You can also update tables data through that browsable object.

```
browse_record.write({'field_name' : field_value})
```

Browsable record list:

```
for obj in browse_obj_list:
    id = obj.id
```

Read more

[Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html)

[Odoo Documentation](http://odoo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: @ EmiproTechnologies Pvt.  That's what my problem is. I tried to access like **id = browse_record.id**. And when i try to view that id value it shows like **browse_record(some.table,21). What can i do for access and store that 21 alone to that id variable?

Comment: @ Emipro Technologies Pvt. I'm looking for a integer value in that id but instead it gives a type of **<class 'openerp.osv.orm.browse_record_list'>**

Comment: it's browsable record list you can access it view iteration or via index, see updated answer. You should write like this **id = browse_record[0].id**.

Comment: Thanks for reply @ Emipro. I know this and i did earlier before this. But now i got this issue.

Comment: Can you please update your question with code and issue you face ? So that I can help you better.

Comment: Thanks for reply @ Emipro. I know this and i did earlier before this successfully. But now i got this issue. It returns only 1 record. When i try to access like you mentioned **for obj in browse_obj_list:
    some_id = obj.id** it gives **NotImplementedError: Iteration is not allowed on browse_record(some.table, 1)**

Comment: `d_c=None
dc=None

        
        dc=self.pool.get('some.table').browse(cr,uid,1,context={})
        for rec in dc:
            d_c=rec.some_id
        logging.info(d_c)` This is my code.

Comment: Actually that d_c variable should have a integer value(21) from that some_id column. But it has **browse_record(some.table,21)** when i view that in log.

Comment: `d_c=None`
`dc=self.pool.get('some.table').browse(cr,uid,1,context={})`
`if dc:`
 `d_c = rec.id`

Comment: If you pass list of ids to browse method then it will return list of browse record, and if you pass single id to the browse it will give you single browsable object.

Comment: i have passed a single id only, even though i cant browse that object?

Comment: Can you please post you code of that page ? update code in question please.

Comment: OMG! I can access all the columns in that table as you said. But that particular column alone is not returning a interger value!!!!!!

Comment: There is a problem of data type you passed to the browse method, ids must be an integer, if you pass str there then you will face issue like this, you can access all the properties of that class except relational. check it.

Comment: **You are correct. browse_record can be accessed like** `partner_id = sale_order_object.partner_id.id` All because of my fault. I did not tried this type of access at first time itself. Thanks for your help